# Python: Merging multiple dictionaries with the same keys and different values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiple dictionaries, where every dictionary has the same keys but different values, for example:

- Dict 1: `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}`
- Dict 2: `{"a":4,"b":7,"c":1}`
- Dict 3: `{"a":6,"b":5,"c":6}`
- ...

Is there an elegant way to merge these dictionaries into one which should be looking something like this?

```
{"a":[1,4,6],"b":[2,7,5],"c":[3,1,6]}
```

Or would it even be more useful to simply put all dictionaries into a list like this:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":4,"b":7,"c":1},{"a":6,"b":5,"c":6}]
```

Comment: Take the solution with `collections.defaultdict(list)` (2nd) in the accept answer

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting!